# HTML - why element with hidden="false" is not visible

Tags: html, css

I have a view in freemarker. And when I'm loading my template, I'm checking if one value is null. If yes, then I want to make my `div` hidden on start. If no, then I want to my `div` being visible. Could someone tell me, why this attempt doesn't work?

```
<div class="..." hidden="false"></div>
```

**No matter if** `hidden` **is true or false, div is not visible. Why?**

Full code example:

```
<#if errorMessageNameList??>
    <#assign hideForm="false" />
<#else>
    <#assign hideForm="true" />
</#if>
<div class="saveEquipmentPanel" hidden="${hideForm}">
    <@saveEquipmentPanel />
</div>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because `hidden` doesn't need a value: it either is `hidden`, or it isn't. The boolean you're sending is ignored. So, basically only add `hidden` if it should be `hidden` and add nothing if it should show.

Comment: What is the alternative that accepts boolean values?

Comment: it'd be easier to change what hideForm is changed to: instead of true/false, change it to a css class that is visible and one that's hidden. <div class="saveEquipmentPanel ${hideForm}">